# Redis in action - unfair semaphore

Tags: redis, semaphore

I'm reading [Redis in action e-book](https://redislabs.com/community/ebook/) chapter about [semaphores](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-6-application-components-in-redis/6-3-counting-semaphores/6-3-1-building-a-basic-counting-semaphore/). Here is the python code to implement semaphore using redis

```
def acquire_semaphore(conn, semname, limit, timeout=10):
   identifier = str(uuid.uuid4())

   now = time.time()

   pipeline = conn.pipeline(True)
   pipeline.zremrangebyscore(semname, '-inf', now - timeout)

   pipeline.zadd(semname, identifier, now)

   pipeline.zrank(semname, identifier)
   if pipeline.execute()[-1] < limit:

      return identifier

   conn.zrem(semname, identifier)

   return None
```

> This basic semaphore works well—it’s simple, and it’s very fast. But
>   relying on every process having access to the same system time in
>   order to get the semaphore can cause problems if we have multiple
>   hosts. This isn’t a huge problem for our specific use case, but if we
>   had two systems A and B, where A ran even 10 milliseconds faster than
>   B, then if A got the last semaphore, and B tried to get a semaphore
>   within 10 milliseconds, B would actually “steal” A’s semaphore without
>   A knowing it.

I didn't catch what does it mean: if `A ran even 10 milliseconds faster than B` then `B would actually “steal” A’s semaphore without A knowing it.`

My thoughts: A's time is `10:10:10:200` and B's time `10:10:10:190` and A've got semaphore. Then B tries to get semaphore within 10 ms (now B's local time is `10:10:10:200`). B will delete expired items and add itslef. How B can `steal` A's semaphore? At the same time if A's time is `10:59` and B's time is `11:02` it's possible when B can remove A's semaphore because of time difference. But it's not the case described in book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If B runs 10 ms slower than A, then B's score is smaller than A, since we use the local time as the score of sorted set.

So B's rank, i.e. `pipeline.zrank(semname, identifier)`, is smaller than A's rank, which is smaller than `limit`, i.e. `if pipeline.execute()[-1] < limit:`. And B thought it got the semaphore, i.e. `return identifier`. In fact, it *steals* the semaphore from A.

Comment: Ah, how I missed it?! You made my day